# Possible to change links and redirect with htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting, hyperlink

This is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteRule ^genre/(.*)$ /index.php?genre=$1 [R=301]
```

The mod_rewrite works, but so does the old link example:

> /index.php?genre=action

Still works. I want to redirect it to:

> /genre/action

**Problem:** They both work, I want the old one to redirect to the new one.

And is it possible to change links with .htaccess. Some sort of url replacing?

My links still says:

> www.site.com/index.php?genre=action

I want it to change it to:

> www.site.com/genre/action

Or do I have to do this manually?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`[R=301]` leads to a HTTP redirect with status code 301.

Just write

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteRule ^genre/(.*)$ /index.php?genre=$1
```

to rewrite the urls on the server side.

Comment: I'm using it now. http://www.animetard.com/?genre=action still works and does not redirect and the link "Action" is still showing `http://www.animetard.com/?genre=action`

Comment: The solution does not prevent the usage of ?genre=action, but http://www.animetard.com/genre/action works now with out changing the url.

Comment: I edited the post to provide a solution with prevents the usage of ?genre=action.

Comment: Does not redirect me or anything :/ thanks for trying though.

Comment: Well, actually you're right. Query parameters are not matched by "RewriteRule". Best solution would be to make sure that only urls like /genre/action are used by your website.